# linux systemd service on port 80

Tags: node.js, linux, centos7, systemd

I try to create systemd service on centos7:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Weeki Server
Requires=After=mongod.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/node/myapp/bin/www
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog               # Output to syslog
StandardError=syslog                # Output to syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-weeki
User=weeki
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=80

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i use port 8080 the service start successfully, but when i change the port to 80, the service failed to start.
I try to open the firewall with the command:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

But it still not working.

Comment: Well either you lack permission to bind to that port or it is already used by some other service.

Comment: I am root, 
When i run the node server not from the service on port 80 its working..

Comment: So that leaves the other option I named, doesn't it? Or that `root` does _not_ have permisson to bind to that port, this might be the case if the SELinux extension is used.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: I'd say start by finding out if another service is already using that port. And by finding out if that system uses the SELinux extension. Another easy approach would be to take a look into the log files. I'd expect those log files to be even mentioned if you start that service manually. _Did_ you look into those? What do they say?

Comment: I disable the SElinux and it still not working.
I dont know where to find the logs for that service

Comment: No further comment until you react to the other aspects I mentioned.

Comment: The port not in use

Comment: @arkascha I'm not sure if that person is ignoring the advice but it seems so. I wrote an answer but it might a waste of time. Still, if you have any comments to the answer please let me know. Maybe at least it will be useful to other people who search for this topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the good advises that you got in the comments by **arkascha**.

**First of all - what's the error?**

What you can do to test if it's a problem of the user **not being able to bind to low ports** is trying use ports like 81, 82, 83 etc. If you still cannot bind to those ports then **you likely don't have the permission**. If you can, then it's not about permissions and **the port is already used** by some other process.

To see if you can **open a given port** by that user try running netcat:

```
nc -l 80
```

where 80 is the port number. Try low ports like 80, 81, 82 and high ports like 8080, 8081, 8082.

To see if **anything is listening** to that port try running:

```
curl http://localhost:80/
```

or:

```
nc localhost 80
```

To see **open ports on your system** run:

```
netstat -lnt
```

To see if **other instances of your program** are running, try:

```
ps aux | grep node
ps aux | grep npm
ps aux | grep server.js
```

If all else fails, you can restart and see if the problem remains:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

That should give you a **clean state** with no old processes hanging around.

### Update

What you can do to listen on port 80 without running as root.
There are few things that you can do:

#### Drop privileges

You can start as root and drop privileges as soon as you open a port:

```
app.listen(80, function () {
  try {
    process.setuid('weeki');
    process.setgid('weeki');
    console.log('Listening on port 80');
    console.log('User:', process.getuid(), 'Group:', process.getgid());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot drop privileges');
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Pros: You don't need to use anything other than your Node program.

Cons: You need to start as root.

See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id
- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setgid_id

#### Reverse proxy

Your Node app can listen on high port like 3000 and you start nginx or other web server to listen on port 80 and proxy requests to port 3000.

Example nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Pros: You don't need to start as root. You can host multiple domains on the same server. You can serve static content directly by nginx without hitting your Node app.

Cons: You need to install and run another software (like nginx).

#### Route tables

You can redirect the incoming traffic on port 80 to port 3000 with `iptables`:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

(you need to run it as root)

Pros: No new software to install. No need to run the Node app as root.

Cons: Static content is served by your Node app. Hosting more than one app per server is not practical.

See:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

#### Allow low port for non-root

This is not always available but also an option. You can use the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability in the Linux kernel:

> CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
>
> - Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port
>              numbers less than 1024).

Pros: No need to run other software. No need to start Node app as root. No need to mess with route tables.

Cons: Not practical to host more than one app per server. Needs using capabilities that may not be available on every system.

See:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Comment: I tried to run the service with user weeki and not root. 
Now i run the service with root and that success.
How could i give user weeki the privilage to run service on port 80?

Comment: @rontoDay I added some ways to listen on port 80 with user "weeki" - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to start a Systemd service as a user other than root, by default your service won't be able to listen on a port below 1024 (known as privileged ports). To allow for this, meaning your server will be able to listen on port 80 without running as root, just add this line to the `[Service]` section of your unit file.

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

For example, if your service was named app.service, you would do the following:

```
sudo systemctl edit app.service

# add the text below to the editor in the designated section
[Service]
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

# save the file and reload the service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

At that point your service should start.

Comment: Presumably this is not applicable for `systemctl --user` invocations?

Answer (score 1):

User should have root privileges to open ports below 1024.